# Using jq to extract values from column-oriented JSON and format in CSV

Tags: csv, json, jq

I have the below JSON file, with the data stored as columns enumerated by `rank` in an array:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "displayName": "First Name",
      "rank": 1,
      "value": "VALUE"
    },
    {
      "displayName": "Last Name",
      "rank": 2,
      "value": "VALUE"
    },
    {
      "displayName": "Position",
      "rank": 3,
      "value": "VALUE"
    },
    {
      "displayName": "Company Name",
      "rank": 4,
      "value": "VALUE"
    },
    {
      "displayName": "Country",
      "rank": 5,
      "value": "VALUE"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to have a CSV file in this format, where the header come from the value of a column's `displayName` and the data in the column is the singular `value` key's value:

```
First Name, Last Name, Position, Company Name, Country
VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE
```

Is this possible by using only `jq`? I don't have any programming skills.

Answer (score 83):

jq has a filter, @csv, for converting an array to a CSV string.  This filter takes into account most of the complexities associated with the CSV format, beginning with commas embedded in fields.  (jq 1.5 has a similar filter, @tsv, for generating tab-separated-value files.)

Of course, if the headers and values are all guaranteed to be free of commas and double quotation marks, then there may be no need to use the @csv filter.  Otherwise, it would probably be better to use it.

For example, if the 'Company Name' were 'Smith, Smith and Smith',
and if the other values were as shown below, invoking jq with the "-r" option would produce valid CSV:

```
$ jq -r '.data | map(.displayName), map(.value) | @csv' so.json2csv.json
"First Name","Last Name","Position","Company Name","Country"
"John (""Johnnie"")","Doe","Director, Planning and Posterity","Smith, Smith and Smith","Transylvania"
```

Comment: I was able to 'jq somestuff | map(.) | @csv', very handy! Thanks

Comment: Your example is going to put all of the display names on the first line and all of the values on the second line, instead of having one line per record.

Comment: @Rag This is exactly what the user in the question wants to do.

Answer (score 55):

I prefer to make each record a row in my CSV.

```
jq -r '.data | map([.displayName, .rank, .value] | join(", ")) | join("\n")'
```

Given the data in the question, this outputs

```
First Name, 1, VALUE
Last Name, 2, VALUE
Position, 3, VALUE
Company Name, 4, VALUE
Country, 5, VALUE
```

Comment: What if .value is a number? I receive the error "string and number cannot be added"

Comment: @Cos something like `.value|tostring` instead of `.value` in the above example

Comment: @Cos, I found parenthesis are required. `(.value|tostring)`

Comment: Also, use `jq -r` to strip the quotes

Comment: ... but this was not what the user in the question asked for.

Comment: @Kusalananda True, but due to the broad question title, many people are visiting this page to find what this answer achieves.

Comment: @conbask The question is clear enough as it is, showing exactly what should be done.

Comment: @Kusalananda The question content is specific and great, but the *title* is broad. This answer has the second-most upvotes because people are looking for this particular solution and arriving here due to the title.

Answer (score 35):

Given just this file, you can do something like:

```
<testfile jq -r '.data | map(.displayName), map(.value) | join(", ")'
```

The `.` operator selects a field from an object/hash. Thus, we start with `.data`, which returns the array with the data in it. We then map over the array twice, first selecting the displayName, then selecting the value, giving us two arrays with just the values of those keys.  For each array, we join the elements with ", " forming two lines.  The `-r` argument tells `jq` to not quote the resulting strings.

If your actual file is longer (ie, has entries for more than one person), you will likely need something a bit more complicated.

Comment: It is not working for me. In a related topic, the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960857/how-to-convert-arbirtrary-simple-json-to-csv-using-jq is both working and very well explained!

Comment: This will list all `.displayName` fields comma separated and after that it will list all the `.value` fields in a comma separated list. The aim is to have a line that has `<.displayname>, <.value>` for every line

Answer (score 13):

I've found `jq` hard to wrap my head around. Here's some Ruby:

```
ruby -rjson -rcsv -e '
  data = JSON.parse(File.read "file.json")
  data["data"].collect {|item| [item["displayName"], item["value"]]}
              .transpose
              .each {|row| puts row.to_csv}
'
```

```
First Name,Last Name,Position,Company Name,Country
VALUE,VALUE,VALUE,VALUE,VALUE
```

The ruby JSON parser barfed about the trailing comma before the close bracket.

Answer (score 3):

Since you tagged this `python` and assuming name of `json` file is `x.json`

```
import os, json
with open('x.json') as f:
    x  = json.load(f)
    print '{}{}{}'.format(', '.join(y['displayName'] for y in x['data']), os.linesep,
             ', '.join(y['value'] for y in x['data']))
First Name, Last Name, Position, Company Name, Country
VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE
```

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
INPUT | jq -r '[.[][].displayName], [.[][].value]| join(", ")'
```

...got me...

```
First Name, Last Name, Position, Company Name, Country
VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE
```

How it works in a nutshell:

1. I traversed through to the third level of data objects using the empty `[]` index field form and `.dot` notation.
2. Once deep enough I specified the data fields I wanted by name like `.[][].displayName`.
3. I assured that my desired fields were self-associated by returning them as separate array objects like `[.[][].displayName], [.[][].value]`
4. And then piped those objects to the `join(", ")` function to be joined as separate entities.

In truth doing `[.field]` is merely another way to `map(.field)` but this is a little more specific in that it specifies the depth level for retrieving the desired data.

Answer (score 2):

Old question but it seems like all the answers recommend indexing by `displayName`, which to me doesn't make sense. CSV is not an indexed format, it's a list of rows, so it's illogical that you have to index by something. The only exception is https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/673753/488462, which would be my preference in practice, except that it uses csvkit while the question is explicitly about jq.

So here's a jq-only way in two steps:

- Construct a header: `cat data.json | jq '.[0] | keys_unsorted | @csv' > data.csv`
- Transform the values: `cat data.json | jq '.[] | map(values) | @csv' >> data.csv`

You can combine these into one command with `tee`, or construct a complex jq query that does both things, if you want, but I think this version is already good enough.

Note that you have to use `keys_unsorted` because `keys` will sort your keys (while `values` doesn't) resulting in mismatched columns. Also, while usually people want both steps, technically the CSV format does not require a header - it is just an optional convenience (and not always desirable). So in those cases you may omit the header.

Lastly, your example input is needlessly wrapped in an object called `data`. I assume you unpack this with a trivial command like `cat input.json | jq '.data' > data.json`, since it isn't really relevant to what's being asked (transforming to CSV).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `rank` is included in the data to specify the correct ordering of the columns, if the columns happen to be listed out of order, we may use that `rank` value to construct an array of headers and values to be converted to CSV like so:

```bash
jq -r '
    reduce .data[] as $col ([]; .[$col.rank - 1] = [$col.displayName, $col.value]) |
    transpose[] | @csv' file
```

The data after the `reduce` is the equivalent of this:

```json
[
   [ "First Name", "VALUE" ],
   [ "Last Name", "VALUE" ],
   [ "Position", "VALUE" ],
   [ "Company Name", "VALUE" ],
   [ "Country", "VALUE" ]
]
```

Transposing this and feeding it through the `@csv` output filter gives us

```
"First Name","Last Name","Position","Company Name","Country"
"VALUE","VALUE","VALUE","VALUE","VALUE"
```

Ignoring the `rank` value, we may simplify the expression by replacing the `reduce` with a simple `map`:

```bash
jq -r '.data | map([.displayName, .value]) | transpose[] | @csv' file
```