# reformat json using jq

Tags: bash, csv, json, jq

I have the below JSON file:

```
{ data : [
  {
   "name" : "name1"
   "date" : [
     {
      "date1" : "aaa",
      "date2" : "bbb"
     },
     {
      "date1" : "ccc",
      "date2" : "ddd"
     },
     {
      "date1" : "eee",
      "date2" : "fff"
     },
     "var" : "ggg"
 },
{
   "name" : "name2"
   "date" : [
     {
      "date1" : "hhh",
      "date2" : "iii"
     },
     {
      "date1" : "jjj",
      "date2" : "kkk"
     },
     "var" : "lll"
  }
 ]
}
```

I would like to have CSV file in this format:

```
name, date, var
name1, aaa ccc eee, ggg
name2, hhh jjj, lll
```

Is this possible by using only jq?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using jq to extract values and format in CSV](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163845/using-jq-to-extract-values-and-format-in-csv)

Comment: @StephenHarris One extra issue in _this_ query is that the data under `date` is not plain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your JSON document is well formed, like the following modified variant of the text that you present:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "name1",
      "date": [
        {
          "date1": "aaa",
          "date2": "bbb"
        },
        {
          "date1": "ccc",
          "date2": "ddd"
        },
        {
          "date1": "eee",
          "date2": "fff"
        }
      ],
      "var": "ggg"
    },
    {
      "name": "name2",
      "date": [
        {
          "date1": "hhh",
          "date2": "iii"
        },
        {
          "date1": "jjj",
          "date2": "kkk"
        }
      ],
      "var": "lll"
    }
  ]
}
```

We could then do the following:

```bsh
$ jq -r '[ "name", "date", "var" ], (.data[] | [.name, ([.date[].date1] | join(" ")), .var]) | @csv' file
"name","date","var"
"name1","aaa ccc eee","ggg"
"name2","hhh jjj","lll"
```

The `jq` expression, with a bit of more air to show the structure:

```
[ "name", "date", "var" ],
(
    .data[] |
    [
      .name,
      ( [ .date[].date1 ] | join(" ") ),
      .var
    ]
) |
@csv
```

This first creates the CSV header as an array of strings. It then iterates over the top-level `data` array, pulling out the values of the `name` and `var` keys into an array.  It also picks out all values for the `date1` sub-keys in the `date` array, and concatenates them with spaces as delimiters.

The CSV header array, along with the array constructed for each `data` element, are then processed for output using `@csv`, which quotes each string and delimited the elements by commas.

---

Another variant:

```bsh
box% jq -r '.data[].date |= ( [.[].date1] | join(" ") ) | [ (.data[0] | keys[]) ], (.data[]| [.[]]) | @csv' file
"date","name","var"
"name1","aaa ccc eee","ggg"
"name2","hhh jjj","lll"
```

This preprocesses the data so that the part of the expression after the first pipe gets the following input:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "name1",
      "date": "aaa ccc eee",
      "var": "ggg"
    },
    {
      "name": "name2",
      "date": "hhh jjj",
      "var": "lll"
    }
  ]
}
```

The code after the first pipe then only has to extract the keys for the CSV header and then collect the values, without having to worry about what the keys are called.

Again, the `jq` expression with a bit mor air inserted for illustration:

```
.data[].date |= ( [ .[].date1 ] | join(" ") ) |
[ (.data[0] | keys[]) ],
( .data[] | [.[]] ) |
@csv
```

The funky-looking `.data[] | [.[]]` creates a array of the values of all keys in each element of `data`.

If there is a worry that `.[]` applied to a non-array might pull out the values in an order which is different from what `keys` produces, then one could use

```
.data[].date |= ( [ .[].date1 ] | join(" ")) |
(.data[0] | keys) as $keys |
$keys,
( .data[]| [ .[$keys[]] ] ) |
@csv
```

I.e., pull out the headers keys into the variable `$keys`, use that for creating the CSV header *and* for pulling out the data from the elements in the `data` array.  The columns may be in a random order, but at least the header and the rest of the data is in the same random order, and a CSV parser would have no issue pulling out the columns by name.

Comment: thanks! I could make CSV file!